# How do i vertically align my form in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

Dear stackoverflow users,

I am trying to make a simple site with only a register and login page to learn how to make a register and login system using php.
Bootstrap is the css library I use to do the design of the website.
I need to vertically align my login form but the css property `vertical-align: middle;` along with `display: inline-block;` doesn't seem to work.
It only moves the form to the left which I don't want. It is already centered horizontally, I just need it to be centered vertically too.
Is there anything I can do to get the right result?

Here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Website - Login</title>
      <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/loginstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
    <body>

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Brand</a>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div id="loginform" class="container">
        <div class="form">
          <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>
          <br>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="emailAddress">Email address:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" placeholder="Email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="index.html">Cancel</a>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my css code:

```
#loginform {
    max-width: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use an offset approach for centering the form horizontally.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

    <!-- the form content -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO using your form](http://jsfiddle.net/pa2dfbx2/1/)

[More centering examples for Bootstrap](http://www.codeply.com/go/Sv6Z9eR9kk)

---

For centering the box vertically: http://jsfiddle.net/x1cg15e3/

This is an display:table approach, where the row is a table cell getting vertically aligned.

Comment: OP wants to *vertically* align the form.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the form to rest in the center of the screen you can use `position: absolute` to do this.

**Sidenote**: Even though this may simply be for an exercise (as you're learning) it's important to understand/consider how the form may affect your layout on smaller viewports (your navigation, the placement of the form may not be desirable in the center on some smaller screens etc).

Here are Two minimal examples:

Mobile First Example Snippet

```css
.loginform h1 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .loginform {
    max-width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /**FOR DEMO ONLY**/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 30px 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    background: white;
    /**FOR DEMO ONLY**/
  }
}
@media (max-width: 499px) {
  .loginform {
    /**FOR DEMO ONLY**/
    padding: 30px 30px 60px;
    background: rgba(12, 13, 14, 0.055);
    /**FOR DEMO ONLY**/
    min-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="register.html">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Log in</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<form class="loginform" id="loginform">

  <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="emailAddress">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" placeholder="Email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Submit</button>
  <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="index.html">Cancel</a>

</form>
```

Example Snippet

```css
.loginform h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
.loginform {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /**FOR DEMO ONLY**/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  background: white;
  /**FOR DEMO ONLY**/
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .loginform {
    min-width: 100%;
    /**FOR DEMO ONLY**/
    box-shadow: none;
    background: rgba(12, 13, 14, 0.055);
    /**FOR DEMO ONLY**/
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="register.html">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Log in</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<form class="loginform" id="loginform">

  <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="emailAddress">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" placeholder="Email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Submit</button>
  <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="index.html">Cancel</a>

</form>
```

Comment: Oh i see now. I also didn't think about mobile which i should think about. Thank you for this!